# removeClass and fade animation

Tags: jquery

I have this code

```
<ul class="nav sub_nav_home">
    <li id="sub_nav_home1"><a href="#"><span>LINK1</span></a></li>
    <li id="sub_nav_home2"><a href="#"><span>LINK2</span></a></li>
    <li id="sub_nav_home3"><a href="#"><span>LINK3</span></a></li>
</ul>

$("ul.sub_nav_home li").hover(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("current").fadeOut();
});
```

this doesn't seem to display the animation I was after. What this does is making the "li" to dissapear completely.

Basically what I need is to remove the class "current" with a fade out effect and then add it to the next "li" with a fade in effect

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

not sure if you can do this with straight jQuery, but I know jQuery UI has a modified removeClass() that lets you add a duration to remove the class over 
[jQuery UI Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/removeClass)

Answer (score 3):

You can't fade from one class to another.  You have to tell jQuery what properties to animate in the .animate() method.

To get the next li element, use .next().

Comment: thanks. what sort of properties you need in the animate() method to get a fading effect?

Comment: @user : opacity http://api.jquery.com/animate/ but you could use `fadeTo` or any jQuery effects http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK i dont think you can add a fadeOut() to a removeClass(). Someone correct me if i'm wrong!

Comment: You're correct but it's possible of you include jQuery UI in the page. With that you can remove class name with animation.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you could do this with some CSS3.

You just add the following to .current.

```
.current{
    color: #f00;
    background-color: #000;
    transition: color 0.5s, background-color 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s, background-color 0.5s; /* Safari */
}
```

Obviously you'll need to change color/background-color to the attributes you'd like to animate. Otherwise, Cubed Eye's suggestion of including JqueryUI is great, as the removeClass in jQueryUI will do it all for you..