# Jquery Fading in a Class

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a certain way in which the fadeIn method should be used to fade in a class.
I have tried ....

`$(".ipv4val").removeClass("bad").fadeIn("slow")`

.... but this fails to fade the class in.

Any Ideas

Thanks,

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4268423/463065) from the possible duplicate, I think it is what you need!

Comment: What's the problem? **[see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4SXN3/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3g6rd/1/

**HTML:**

`<div class="ip4val bad"></div>​`

**CSS**

`.ip4val{width:200px; height:200px;}
.bad{background:#333;}​`

**Jquery:**

```
$(".ip4val").click(function(){

    $(this).fadeOut('slow', function(){
       $(this).removeClass('bad')
    });
});​
```

***----------Updates-------***

If you just want to fadeout the border of input on focus, its posible with CSS3.

**Working CSS fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/3g6rd/3

Comment: ok thanks, but what about if you only want to remove the border.
As if ip4val is an input then this would fade out the entire input box.

Comment: @felix001 you can do that with CSS3 here is the fiddle 

http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/3g6rd/3/

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of [fadeIn() method](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) is to animate opacity of the element, you can`t animate addition or deletion of a class. You can though animate certain css properties using [animate() method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: I agree though that doesn't completely answer the question. Which would be is there a way to progressively remove a class, which I'm guessing the answer is no...

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4268423/463065)

Comment: What attribute of the class are you trying to progressively remove or animate? Does `$(".ipv4val").fadeIn("slow").removeClass("bad")` make a difference?